# How can I take a screenshot of the current video frame in Skype?

Tags: skype

I want to take a screenshot of only the video part that I am looking at and not the whole screen. It is possible in the Windows version of Skype, where we can just click the <kbd>Take a picture</kbd> button and we get the current video frame (picture) in our gallery.

I've tried it on Ubuntu, but there seems to be no option for it. How can I take a screenshot of the current video frame in Skype on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What do you mean by "picture snaps"? You want to take a screenshot?

Comment: I want to take a screenshot but only the video part that i am looking at not the whole screen. It is possible in windows versions of skype, where we can just  click "take a picture" button and we'll get the current video frame(picture) in our gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [not possible](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1222/what-is-video-snapshot). The page says you need Skype 5.5 for Windows or higher.

You can use [Shutter](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/) to make a screenshot instead. After you've installed Shutter you can bind it to your <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key. Shutter has different modes (from `shutter -h`):

```
-s, --select=[X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT]
        Capture an area of the screen. Providing X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT is optional.
-f, --full
        Capture the entire screen.
-w, --window=[NAME_PATTERN]
        Select a window to capture. Providing a NAME_PATTERN (Perl-style regex) ist optional.
-a, --active
        Capture the current active window.
--section
        Capture a section. You will be able to select any child windowby moving the mouse over it.
-m, --menu
        Capture a menu.
-t, --tooltip
        Capture a tooltip.
--web=[URL]
        Capture a webpage. Providing an URL ist optional.
-r, --redo
        Redo last screenshot.
```

So you could bind <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to `shutter -s` so you can select an area (in your case the area where your Skype video is displaying) to save to an image file.

To bind your <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key to shutter:

1. Search Dash for `Keyboard` and open it
2. Click on `Shortcuts`
3. Click on `Custom shortcuts`
4. Click on `+` to add a new shortcut
5. For the `Name` field, enter `Shutter`
6. For the `Command` field, enter `shutter -s`
7. Click on `Apply`
8. Click on `Disabled` to assign a key
9. Press your <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key
10. Click `Reassign`

Now you can use your <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key to take a screenshot of an area.